# How psycopg2 connect to postgres by kube nodeport host?

Tags: python, postgresql, kubernetes, robotframework, psycopg2

I'll use testarchiver send robotframework output to postgres then grafana hook data from postgres show to dashboard. I have install postgres on kubernetes and use nodeport for access postgres from outside. I use testarchiver(python lib) for send robotframework output to postgres but It error that psycopg2.OperationalError: could not translate host name "my kube ip:30005" to address: Name or service not known.

I config db_config.json for use in testarchiver like this:
{

```
    "db_engine": "postgresql",
    "database": "my_db",
    "host": "my kube ip:30005",
    "port": "5432",
    "user": "root",
    "password": "My Password",
    "require_ssl": "False"
```

}

I thought in host can't use ip with port.

how resolve this problem?

how I set host with port for psycopg2 connect to my postgres?

Answer (score 0):

Set your host to k8s node IP address and your port to 30005 maybe? Assuming that your NodePort service configuration is correct.

Comment: my postgres on port 30005 can access by grafana. I thought My postgres can access but for psycopg2 python libs can't access with host:port.

Answer (score 0):

The `OperationalError: could not translate host name "my kube ip:30005" to address` is a good hint. It's trying some DNS resolution for a name, that includes your NodePort.

Try this instead:

```
"db_engine": "postgresql",
"database": "my_db",
"host": "my-kube-ip",
"port": "30005",
"user": "root",
"password": "My Password",
"require_ssl": "False"
```